# Does C fopen read the entire file into memory?

Tags: c, fopen

I'm wondering if the fopen command is smart enough to stop reading a file if it's to large and then wait for some proceeding read command to continue reading.

For that matter, how large is _iobuf?

Comment: `fopen` does not read any data, it returns a FILE* pointer needed to use file I/O functions like `fread`, `fgetl`, `fprintf`, `fwrite`, `fseek`, `ftell`... `fread` returns the number of bytes read, so if the end of file is reached, that number will be smaller than the number of bytes requested.

Comment: this is a big question a simple answer is that fopen is calling open syscall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fopen(...)` doesn't do any size checks; it just returns a file pointer. Are you thinking of `fread(...)`, by any chance?

You can always find the size of the file that you are going to read by using [stat(...)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/stat.html) system call.

Answer (score 2):

Per the C standard, `setbuf()`/`setvbuf()` shall be called after `fopen()` and before anything else. These set the buffering mode and buffer size for the freshly opened file. This implies that at least at the C level `fopen()` reads nothing from the file it has opened.

The underlying file system implementation in the OS, however, may read ahead into a file cache, but this is clearly not defined in the language standard. You need to find this out in the OS documentation or by experimentation.

`_iobuf` is not defined in the C standard. While I may "guess" what it is, it's unlikely something you need to concern yourself with (it would not contain a fixed-size C file buffer anyway and rather contain a pair of values: a pointer to a buffer and the buffer size).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [here](https://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=572), you'll see that `#define BUFSIZ    1024`
But it depends on your fopen lib implementation. AFAIK, there is no standard definition.